# Regex to generate currency-like formats

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to generate currency like numbers:

Examples:

```
123 -> 123
123.0 -> 123
1234 -> 1,234
1234.00 -> 1,234
12345 -> 12,345
12345.0012 -> 12,345
123456 -> 123,456
123456.02 -> 123,456 and so on..
```

basically it should trim everything after the . including the . and format the rest of the number.

I have this so far to restrict the user to enter only the digits.

```
num.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')
```

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
> new Number(1234.00).toLocaleString()
1,234
```

To limit the number of decimal places to 0, you can use [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) as well:

```
> new Number((12345.0012).toFixed(0)).toLocaleString()
12,345
```

`0` is the default argument to `.toFixed()`, so it can be omitted if you prefer.

Here's a snippet with a working example:

```js
function convert() {
  var num = new Number(document.getElementById("number").value);
  var fixed = new Number(num.toFixed());
  var locale = fixed.toLocaleString();
  alert(locale);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="enter number" id="number" />
<button onclick="convert()">convert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a regular expression (if you insist) matching any number, that could be follow by a dot.

```js
var nums = ['123', '123.0', '1234', '1234.00', '12345.0012', '123456', '123456.02']
var regex = /^(\d+)(?=[\.]?)/

nums.forEach(function(number) {
  var match = number.match(regex)[1];
  var fixed = fixComma(match);
  $('#result').append(number + ' was fixed to ' + fixed + '<br/>')
});


function fixComma(match) {
  var GROUP_LEN = 3;
  var len = match.length;
  if (len > GROUP_LEN) {
    var times = parseInt(len / GROUP_LEN);
    var remider = len % GROUP_LEN;
    var index = (remider > 0) ?  len - (times*GROUP_LEN) : GROUP_LEN;
    return match.substring(0, index) + ',' + fixComma(match.substring(index))
  }
  else  {
    return match
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result' />
```